# how to read substrings from specific patterns

Tags: java, string

I have an input string like `_FIR_abcdef_gh_SEC_ijk1234_LAS_tun_1234`

Assume i need make sub string of `abcdef_gh` , `ijk1234` and `tun_1234`.

`_FIR_` ,`_SEC_` and `_LAS_` are the keys here.

I have tried with sub string options but couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you like this?

public class Substring {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fullString = "_FIR_abcdef_gh_SEC_ijk1234_LAS_tun_1234";

    int start1 = fullString.indexOf("_FIR_");
    int start2 = fullString.indexOf("_SEC_");
    int start3 = fullString.indexOf("_LAS_");

    String first = fullString.substring(start1+5, start2);
    String second = fullString.substring(start2+5, start3);
    String third = fullString.substring(start3+5, fullString.length());


    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);
}
```

}

Console:

abcdef_gh
ijk1234
tun_1234

Comment: Thanks stefan like this I need.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.